# Bash SFTP Script - Too many login attempts looks like a DOS attack

Tags: bash, shell, sftp

I've managed to write a bash script, based on someone's previous work, to send out files via SFTP to a Limoma GoAnywhere application. I'm not fluent in bash or shell. Unfortunately, the GoAnywhere application I'm trying to SFTP files to keeps blacklisting my originating server's IP address.

I was able to get a response from someone who works with the system who told me that there's a limit of 60 login attempts before it will view it as a DOS attack. I'm not sure what the time period is.

The problem with the script below is that it does a login for each and every file that is being sent. I need the login to be done once before the for loop and then send out dozens of files before it closes the connection. This would controlled using a cron job and executed about once an hour. Could anyone please help rewrite this to make a single connect, rather than multiples?

```
#!/bin/bash


today=`date +'%k:%M:%S-%m.%d.%Y'`
nowdate=`date +'%d%H%M'`

xferhome="/home/somefolder"
recdir="$xferhome/fax_incoming_prod"
procdir="$xferhome/fax_processed_prod"

# log stuff..
logfile="$xferhome/log/fax_xfer_prod.log"

# clean up log file @ beginning of every month..
if [ $nowdate -eq "091200" ]; then
        rm $logfile
fi

cd ${recdir}

# start
{

filearray=($(ls -ltr *.{pdf,fmi} 2>/dev/null | awk '{print $9}'))
idx=$((${#filearray[*]} - 1))

if [ $((${#filearray[*]})) -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "${today} Nothing found.."
    exit 2
fi

echo "${today} - send"

for ((i=0;i<=${idx};i++)); do
    echo "SFTP'ing .pdf file: ${filearray[${i}]}"
    fname=${filearray[${i}]}
    export fname
    expect <<'END'

        # Expect Variables

        set FTPUSER someusername
        set FNAME $env(fname)
        set FTPSERVER some.server.net
        set FILEPATH Fax_Queue_Prod
        set FTPPASS somepassword

        spawn /usr/bin/sftp -v -oPort=22 $FTPUSER\@$FTPSERVER
        expect "password:"
        send "$FTPPASS\n"
        expect "sftp>"
        send "cd $FILEPATH\n"
        expect "sftp>"
        send "put $FNAME\n"
        expect "sftp>"
        send "quit\n"

END
    echo "Moving ${filearray[${i}]} to processed directory"
    mv ${filearray[${i}]} ${procdir}/.
done

# logit all.. :)
} >>$logfile 2>>$logfile
```

Comment: Are you being blacklisted for 60 successful logins? Or for unsuccessful attempts?

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be really complicated. Is there a benefit of using sftp instead of scp?

You should be able to all files in one connection with

```
scp -p "${filearray[@]}" $FTPUSER@$FTPSERVER:$FILEPATH
```

The `filearray` is the array of files you want to transfer from your script. It expands to the names of the files you want to transfer. It expands to

```
scp -p "${filearray[1]}" "${filearray[2]}" ... "${filearray[n]}" $FTPUSER@$FTPSERVER:$FILEPATH
```

Comment: It looks like GoAnywhere supports SCP. I don't understand that filearray markup you posted. We want to make sure that the files are moved to a processed directory after they are sent via SFTP (or SCP) to GoAnywhere. There are incoming and processed directories along with a log file. I don't want to move files that are added to the incoming folder during the transfer of files. Would SCP potential cause this problem to occur?

Comment: I added an explanation to the answer.

Comment: For the life of me, I can't get it to work with scp. I has some issues with the password, but I think I got past that. Now it can't find the file(s) no matter what I do. I keep getting various "No such file or directory" errors. I'm not sure if it has something to do with the expect or the mix.